# Arbitrary equivalence of dates

Tags: excel, vba

My code in VBA is as follows to check that each datetime in column A is 15 min after the one before:

```
  For j = 2 To 18
       If Range("A" & j).Value <> DateAdd("n", 15, Range("A" & j - 1).Value) Then   
            Range("C" & j).Value = DateAdd("n", 15, Range("A" & j - 1).Value)
            Range("D" & j).Value = Range("A" & j).Value
       End If
  Next j
```

This is my output when I expect nothing in columns C and D:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jsWw.png)

Why is there a recurring pattern of when the dates are not equivalent even though the output shows that they are?

Comment: The issue you are seeing is because Excel uses number with decimals to store date/time and you are running into the issue that though Excel shows every fifteen minutes in decimal form it is not exact to the value you are looking for it may be off by +/- .00001 or more.  This is not enough to change the minute but is in fact several parts of a second off.

Comment: Damn you number precision!  You have been my bane on more than one occasion.

Comment: Especially when 15 minutes equates to `0.010416666666` with 6 repeating forever.  Excel truncates this to `0.0104166666666667` so depending on when excel rounds it will be off.

Comment: This is VBA as opposed to spreadsheet formulas, but would the VBA code work better if he broke the time down and compare the quivalent of Minutes(a1)<>Minutes(A1)+Time(0,15,0)  or are you still just screwed with the precision aspect?

Comment: @ForwardEd yes `If TimeSerial(Hour(Range("A" & j).Value), Minute(Range("A" & j).Value), 0) <> TimeSerial(Hour(Range("A" & j - 1).Value), Minute(Range("A" & j - 1).Value + 15), 0) Then`